# Using PDF React Renderer, Images do not be displayed when downloaded

Tags: reactjs, image, pdf

I have a strange issue whit React PDF Renderer. I have a document with an Image located on the public folder. There is no problem to displayed the image with de PDFViewer componant.

But If I want to download the document, the image always disapear.

I tried to use Base64 Image, absolute url, and everything possible :)

Inside the doc component :

```js
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Image src="/images/Logo.jpeg" fixed style={styles.headerImage} />
          <Text style={styles.headerTitle} fixed>ORDRE DE FABRICATION</Text>
        </View>
```

When i call the PDF Download

```js
            <PDFDownloadLink
              document={<OFPdf of={of} />}
              fileName={`${of.fp.formule.ref}_${of?.lot}_${of.ref}`}
              style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
            >
              {({
                blob, url, loading, error,
              }) => (
                <Button>
                  {loading ? 'Chargement du document...' : 'Générer l\'OF'}
                </Button>
              )}
            </PDFDownloadLink>
```

Comment: what is the version of `@react-pdf/renderer` in your package.json? also the issue only happen in JPEG image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue is related to `this.bits` ,  it became `undefined`, it is related to the replacement of `jpeg-exif` into `jay-jpeg`
-> [fix: replace jpeg-exif with jay-peg #2591](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/pull/2591).

We can use `@react-pdf/renderer@3.1.5` as a file import in `package.json` (make sure to remove `@react-pdf/renderer`) then run `yarn install`

```
{
   "workspaces": [
       "localReactPackages/**/*"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "react-pdf-render": "file:./localReactPackages/react-pdf-renderer/packages/renderer"
    }
}
```

Make sure to verify if packages are properly sym linked, like the image below
[image]

download the library here: https://github.com/jason-migz/react-pdf-renderer-3-1-5-without-jay-peg/blob/main/react-pdf-renderer-3.1.5.zip

I test it with JPEG images and it's working properly

[image]

Note: Again this is just a TEMPORARY FIX, until the author of `@react-pdf/renderer` fix it

Comment: thx for your answer. In the mean time I just change to format from jpeg to png.